# Yii 1.x Как использовать CActiveRecord в migration

Tags: yii, импорт, миграция

У меня сложная миграция, без моделей не обойтись. Хочу например поднять модель

```
TaskMarks::model()->findByPk(1);
```

Но выдает ошибку

```
PHP Error[2]: include(TaskMarks.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Дело в том, что файл с классом находится в папке `quiz`
В конфиге проекта прописано

```
 // autoloading model and component classes
    'import' => array(
       'application.models.quiz.*',
)
```

Но это не помогает при миграции. Что можно сделать в данном случае?

Не в том файле прописал import. Нужно было в  console.php, а прописал в main.php

Answer (score 1):

Не в том файле прописал import. Нужно было в console.php, а прописал в main.php